# Predicting major product of a reaction with nitrous acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stability, amines

$\hspace{4.5cm}$[image: Reaction]

For the above reaction I am asked to predict $\ce{X}$, the major product.

Of the options given, I thought product (1) would be correct, seeing as how it has the most stable intermediate cation (tertiary) and a highly substituted double bond.

$\hspace{3.9cm}$[image: Products]

The answer however states that product (2) is the major product.

I can't understand why the second product would be favored over the first. There's no obvious stabilizing factor here in product (2).

Comment: Oxonium cations are more stable than tertiary.

Comment: Isn't a secondary carbocation the intermediate and not an oxonium ion for product 2?I mean, after N2 is eliminated and a hydride transer occurs from the carbonyl carbon to the carbocation, isnt a secondary carbocation formed next to electronegative oxygen?

Comment: ...Which is a protonated carbonyl - oxonium cation. Somehow this powerful mesomeric stabilisation is often omitted

Comment: (2) cannot be the major product as of the images you are supplying now unless a carbon source is added. The carbon atoms don’t add up.

Answer (score 5):

I think (2) is correct, but either your or your book erred in writing it. This is what the mechanism (and major product) should be:

[image: Mechanism]